# Unable to get output from shell script command in java

Tags: java, linux, shell

I'm running a shell script command in java program using ProcessBuilder, here is my code :

```
String lastLine = "";

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "echo $(ps -eo pid,args | grep -v grep | grep -v \"$$"\ | grep feature_service.sh | awk '{print $1}')");

BufferedReader reader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                lastLine = line;
            }
```

Output from this : empty string ("")

But if i run the same command on terminal it is working fine (pid of process).

Please help me.

Comment: Does this compile? You've got two unescaped quotes inside a string, in `"$$"` (instead of `\"$$\"`).

Comment: i'm using this \"$$\"  only in my program. thnx i will change here also.

Answer (score 1):

Following simplified Shell command is working.

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", 
    "-c", 
    "ps -eo pid,args|grep [f]eature_service.sh|awk '{print $1}'|tr '\\n' ' '");
```

- `ps -eo pid,args` - list the process ID and the arguments
- `grep [f]eature_service.sh` - grep for the string `feature_service.sh` in the arguments, the `[f]` avoid the multiple usage of `grep` in the chain
- `awk '{print $1}'` - print the first column of the output, using default whitespace characters as delimiter
- `tr '\n' ' '` - replace all newline cracaters in the output by a space character

Comment: command is working on terminal, but getting null (from bufferedReader) if running through java program.

Comment: @vinni I believe you run it differently. If your run `/bin/bash -c echo $(...)` in the terminal it returns nothing.

Comment: thnx or help, I'm using pgrep -f  feature_service.sh and its  working fine.